# "Could not evaluate the 'color' mapping" error in Plotnine

Tags: python, mapping, visualization, python-ggplot, plotnine

I'm having an issue with Plotnine on python everything is working fine except when I attempt to specify a color in aes I get an error saying:

> PlotnineError: "Could not evaluate the 'color' mapping: 'black'
>   (original error: name 'black' is not defined)"

I have tried importing palettes but that has not worked.

```
from mizani.palettes import *
from palettable import *

ggplot(aes(x = 'Dest', y = 'AVG', color = 'Dest'),f) + geom_point(aes(size = 'Revenue'))+scale_size_continuous(range = (1,15))+geom_text(aes(label='Dest', color = 'black'),va='bottom')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
geom_text(aes(label='Dest', color = 'black'),va='bottom')
```

Should be

```
geom_text(aes(label='Dest'), color='black', va='bottom')
```

There is a difference between mapping values to an aesthetic and manually setting the value of an aesthetic. Everything in `aes` maps values to the aesthetic and those values (or expressions) should refer to columns in the dataframe. If that is not the case then you are most likely making a mistake.